# Top bar follows you?

Tags: feature-request

Can we make the top black bar stay with you as you move down, so that you can check your reputation? It would be useful if the idea goes forward.

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101385/should-the-top-navigation-be-frozen. This feature has already been requested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I would like to see such a feature, but as it turns out, the same question was already asked on Meta SO:

[Should the top navigation be frozen (optional)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101385/should-the-top-navigation-be-frozen)

As you can see there, it probably won't be implemented. However, there are workarounds so that you could achieve a similar result using various scripts/stylesheets.

Comment: Should I delete the question?

Comment: Don't delete it. Leave it here for the record.